# How to fire an alert when a Jenkins job runs for too long?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to be alerted when my Jenkins jobs run for too long.
I didn't find such a plugin, do you know of such a plugin, or another way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: If "someone knows" you'll get an answer.. no point asking such in titles.

Answer (score 9):

As far as I know there is no such plugin or configuration available. There is [buildtimeout-plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build-timeout+Plugin), which will abort the build on a given timeout, but AFAIK doesn't support just giving an alert and not aborting.

if you're willing to make a custom build of the plugin, it might be reasonable to extend that yourself. Like you can see from its [source code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/build-timeout-plugin), it defines a general [BuildTimeoutOperation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/build-timeout-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/build_timeout/BuildTimeOutOperation.java) interface which should be extendable to give an alert on build timeout instead of aborting a build. The [existing implementations of the interface](https://github.com/jenkinsci/build-timeout-plugin/tree/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/build_timeout/operations) could give you some ideas on how that would be done.

Comment: I already considered those options. But thanks for your answer!  (+vote)

Comment: @AviY you probably should explain also in the question which options you've already considered and why they didn't suite you

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

For **sound & mail alert** :

-> Use [**Jenkins Sounds plugin**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Sounds+plugin) & **build triggers** to achieve your task.

Create a separate job for alert and trigger the job when you want. (stable, unstable or failed)

In that same job itself, you can configure email notification.

To find **long running** job, Use parallel (time counter configuration or use [build-timeout plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build-timeout+Plugin)) job. If it takes time more than specified then trigger an alert job (configured with sound or email)